OSRM routing 504 Gateway Time-out
Don't build a route using the api:
https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407;13.428555,52.523219?overview=false
Returns 504.
It also does not work on the official website:
https://map.project-osrm.org/?z=12&center=52.519250%2C13.457909&loc=52.530634%2C13.381348&loc=52.507027%2C13.399200&hl=en&alt=0&srv=0
What could be the problem?

Odd: foot & bike profiles work fine but driving does not.
Running OSRM with Docker does give a valid route for 13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407;13.428555,52.523219
Steps: https://github.com/evgeniyarbatov/berlin-osrm
